# res.json doesn't seem to show the json data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am creating APIs based on a local *ads.js* file (for now).

The res.json in main API **/api/ads** which shows all the ads (json) works fine, but the res.json in the second API **/api/ads/:id** does not seem to show anything.

I'm running the server using nodemon.

Code is below:

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import ads from './data/ads.js'

dotenv.config()

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running...')
})

app.get('/api/ads', (req, res) => {
  res.json(ads)                                          // Works Fine
})

app.get('/api/ads/:id', (req, res) => {
  const ad = ads.find((a) => a._id === req.params.id)    // Is the problem here?
  res.json(ad)                                           // Does not show anything
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${MODE} mode on port ${PORT}`))
```

Here is the ads.js file:

```
const ads = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    img: '/images/feat.webp',
    title: 'Hyundai Tuscon CRDi 2017',
    price: 3000000
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    img: '/images/innova.jpg',
    title: 'Toyota Innova Crysta 2019',
    price: 1200000
  }
]

export default ads
```

The folder structure is:

```
backend
|--data
|----ads.js
|--server.js
frontend
*more files*
package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.params` will hold an object of key-value pairs where the values are always strings. This means you're comparing a number-type to a string using [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#strict_equality_using) (`===`), which will obviously return false and which will result in an empty `ad` array.

You can try to convert the param-id to a number and then compare the values or use the loose comparison operator (`==` instead of `===`, although I do not recommend this):

```
app.get('/api/ads/:id', (req, res) => {
  const ad = ads.find((a) => a._id === Number.parseInt(req.params.id))   
  res.json(ad)                                           
})
```

Comment: Now that's something new I came to know, Thank you